E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable
I am running
$ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

on a Chromebook.
$ which bash file mkdir rm which
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/file
/usr/bin/mkdir
/usr/bin/rm
/usr/bin/which

$ sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y;
35 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 191 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main arm64 base-files arm64 12.4+deb12u5 [70.8 kB]
...
Get:35 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main arm64 usbutils arm64 1:014-1+deb12u1 [70.2 kB]

$ sudo gpg --no-default-keyring         --keyring /etc/apt/keyrings/google-chrome.gpg         --import /tmp/google.pub
gpg: keybox '/etc/apt/keyrings/google-chrome.gpg' created
gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key A040830F7FAC5991: public key "Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>" imported
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: public key "Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:               imported: 2

$ sudo echo 'deb [arch=arm64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/google-chrome.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main'
 | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
deb [arch=arm64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/google-chrome.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

$ sudo apt-get update -y; sudo apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
Get:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,825 B]
Hit:2 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease                           
Hit:3 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Hit:4 https://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Ign:5 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/123 bookworm InRelease
Hit:6 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/123 bookworm Release
Fetched 1,825 B in 3s (525 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable


The Chrome repository doesn’t provide arm64 packages:

N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'

On Linux, Google Chrome is only available for x86 systems. You could install Chromium instead, using the Debian package which is available for your architecture.

It's worth noting that chromium, the open-source, non-Google-Spyware variant of Chrome, is in debian's default repositories, and also exists for arm64. OP should possible try to use that instead.
